# Resuming PostgreSQL logical replication (missing pg_stat_replication entry)

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-14, sysdba

I implemented a logical replication on PostgreSQL 14 (from AWS to on-premise) via windows. A few days we experience internet lags. When i checked the pg_stat_replication in publication source, it was totally empty but the pg_replication_slots has one row entry. I tried executing "alter subscription <subscription_name> refresh publication" and also "alter subscription <subscription_name> disable/enable" in the subscriber side but still no entry  on the pg_stat_replication under publication source. What is the proper way to resume/continue the logical replication on the subscriber side?